# Is an IDN valid in a src attribute or does it have to be Punycode-encoded?

Tags: html, idn, punycode

In an UTF-8 encoded HTML document, is it valid to use an [IDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) as a value for `src` and `href` attributes?

```
<a href="http://موقع.وزارة-الاتصالات.مصر/">ICT</a>
```

Are there any objections that enforce the use of the Punycode-encoded version?

```
<a href="http://xn--4gbrim.xn----ymcbaaajlc6dj7bxne2c.xn--wgbh1c/">ICT</a>
```

I’m not sure if modern user agents treat a `href` as an “[IDN-unaware domain name slot](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3490.txt)”.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the HTML specification for [a-tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element) is says that `href` is a [hyperlink](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/links.html#hyperlink).

When I answered this in 2014, it said that href was an URI and that URI was defined in [RFC3987 Internationalized Resource Identifiers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987). If you follow the links from hyperlink, you find a link to the [URL: Living standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-url) that mentions both RFC 3986 and RFC 3987 in the Goal.

From RFC 3987:

> **Abstract**
>
> This document defines a new protocol element, the Internationalized
> Resource Identifier (IRI), as a complement to the Uniform Resource
> Identifier (URI).  An IRI is a sequence of characters from the
> Universal Character Set (Unicode/ISO 10646).  A mapping from IRIs to
> URIs is defined, which means that IRIs can be used instead of URIs,
> where appropriate, to identify resources.

So the simple answer is: yes, you can use idn in href, at least for HTML 5 documents. You should however look at RFC 3987 section 4 if your text is bidirectional.

This answer was updated in 2018, after [JohnT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3062923/johnt) asked me to update the broken links.

Comment: Could you please update the first two links? They are broken.

Comment: What I see in the 5.2 standard is "The href attribute on a and area elements must have a value that is a valid URL potentially surrounded by spaces." Following the chain of links starting with "valid URL potentially surrounded by spaces" one ends up at a vague statement that " one may wish to consider [RFC3986] [RFC3987]". But one of these defines URI (no non-ASCII) while the other defines IRI, Which is valid is therefore still unclear.